# Case statement is ignoring where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

I am trying to create a SQL statement that returns multiple counts.   The count below works as I expect, but the case statement is ignoring the where clause for my query.

I'm trying to get the total number of PacketId's that meet the where criteria.  Then get a second total showing the sum of PacketId's that meet the where criteria and have a StatusId of 3.

*edit Table1 and Table2 both share PacketId as a foreign key.

```
Select 
Count(Distinct wpq.PacketId) AS Total,
SUM(Case When wpq.StatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OtherCount
FROM [Table1] ppo JOIN [Table2] wpq ON ppo.PacketId = wpq.PacketId
WHERE wpq.CreateDate between  '11/1/2017' and '1/1/2018' and ppo.IsSelected = 1
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data and what it is returning currently? That might help to figure out why the case statement doesn't return what you want.

Comment: Are you looking for the number of unique `StatusID`s or the total number? There's nothing incorrect in terms of syntax about that CASE statement so there's something wrong with your logic. Also, you're implicitly casting to a date in your WHERE clause. Please do this explicitly using the correct format model to avoid errors. Finally, is this SQL Server?

Comment: You query looks like T-SQL but you should always indicate dbms type in the tags. By itself `sql` isn't usually sufficient. +fyi: correct term is `case expression` (not case statement) as they evaluate to single values.

Comment: I am running this query in SQL Management Studio 2012, just trying to pin down a working query so I can use it for some web development.   I'm looking for the number of Distinct PacketId's overall that fall within the time frame specified in the where clause.    Then I need to also pull back the number of distinct PacketIds that have a StatusId = 3.   (In the same query)

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Which dbms is this????

Comment: I can't export any actual data unfortunately, but right now my total count is coming back with a value of 5 but my otherCount has a value of 28.  (which obviously would not be possible since it should be less than the total.    If I manually run a query against the table to pull packets that have my date span and status = 3 there should only be one row returned.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, then add SQL Server tag.  It's useless if someone give you query to the wrong dbms.

Comment: Can't really help without sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may be getting a higher number than expected for the `othercount` but that may be due to the use of `count(distinct...)` which reduces the first column result, but not the second. Perhaps introducing a subquery to select only distinct values would help?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      wpq.PacketId
    , wpq.StatusId
FROM [Table1] ppo
JOIN [Table2] wpq ON ppo.PacketId = wpq.PacketId
WHERE wpq.CreateDate BETWEEN '11/1/2017' AND '1/1/2018'
AND ppo.IsSelected = 1
;
```

then count from that, e.g:

```
SELECT
      COUNT(PacketId)                                 AS total
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN StatusId = 3 THEN StatusId END) AS othercount
    , SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS othersum
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT
            wpq.PacketId
          , wpq.StatusId
      FROM [Table1] ppo
      JOIN [Table2] wpq ON ppo.PacketId = wpq.PacketId
      WHERE wpq.CreateDate BETWEEN '11/1/2017' AND '1/1/2018'
      AND ppo.IsSelected = 1
      ) AS d
;
```

Note: the `COUNT()` function ignores nulls, so I have added an alternative calculation method to consider. I prefer to use `COUNT()` in such a query.

Also I would like to note that your use of what appears to be M/D/YYYY date literals is NOT safe. The safest date literal format in T-SQL is YYYYMMDD. Similarly using between is not best practice for date ranges and wpuld encourage you to use `>=` and `<` instead, like so:

```
SELECT
      COUNT(PacketId)                                 AS total
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN StatusId = 3 THEN StatusId END) AS othercount
    , SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS othersum
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT
            wpq.PacketId
          , wpq.StatusId
      FROM [Table1] ppo
      JOIN [Table2] wpq ON ppo.PacketId = wpq.PacketId
      WHERE wpq.CreateDate >= '20171101' AND wpq.CreateDate < '20180101'
      AND ppo.IsSelected = 1
      ) AS d
;
```

Note I'm not sure if you do want to include 1/1/2018, if you do then use `< '20180102'` instead

Comment: Thank you!   This worked perfectly!   Have a great evening.

Comment: Great, good to know. It is helpful to everyone else that you "accept" a correct answer. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Absolutely, I just accepted it.   ( I tried to vote it as useful but that isn't allowed until my reputation is 15)

Comment: :) thanks. By accepting you gain 2 points to help you get past 15 rep points. (*Perhaps you haven't done this in past questions?*)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use standard date formats.  Most databases support YYYY-MM-DD:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wpq.PacketId) AS Total,
       SUM(Case When wpq.StatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OtherCount
FROM [Table1] ppo JOIN
     [Table2] wpq
     ON ppo.PacketId = wpq.PacketId
WHERE wpq.CreateDate >= '2017-11-01' AND
      wpq.CreateDate <= '2018-01-01' AND
      ppo.IsSelected = 1;
```

It is possible that the date comparisons are really being done as strings, so they do not do what you expect.